# Animating an inline element's position().left

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm attempting to move a randomly located inline `<a>` horizontally using jQuery.

After reading about this seems like you have to change the element's position from the default 'static' to 'relative'.

But isn't it possible to just animate the `position().left` value?

Couldn't figure it out as most answers reffer to animation `left`, which requires `poistion: relative`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But isn't it possible to just animate the `position().left` value?

Well, what *is* the `position().left` value?

jQuery isn't magic. Under the hood, the `animate` method simply modifies `element.style.left` over and over to create a smooth transition. `element.style` is a convenience property that allows you to modify the contents of the element's `style` attribute, which in turn is one way apply CSS rules to a specific element.

So to answer your question: no, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

that's the main idea of simple elements animation with jQuery, as i see it:

html:

```
<a id="moving" href="#">test</a>
```

css:

```
#moving{position:relative;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#moving').animate({ left: '+=800' }, 8000); // this is RELATIVE positioning
    // or
    $('#moving').animate({ left: '1000px' }, 8000); // this is ABSOLUTE positioning
});
```

hope that helps.

Comment: I haven't seen that `+=` trick used before. Is that a CSS thing or a jquery one?